# why F# Closure context does not evaluate to new value?

Tags: f#

I am trying to understand Closure in F#. Based on the question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924/f-closure) my understanding is that, it is the process of carrying context around. One of the answers had a very simple solution like the following

```
let addCounter = 
    let counter = ref 0
    (fun () -> incr counter; !counter)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let firstCounter = addCounter()
    printfn "%A" firstCounter
    printfn "%A" firstCounter
let k = Console.ReadKey()
```

I created a high order function called firstCounter and I was expecting the first output to be 1 and the second output to be 2. But when I ran, I get both the answers as 1. Is it something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to run this:

```
let addCounter = 
    let counter = ref 0
    (fun () -> incr counter; !counter)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%d" (addCounter ())
    printfn "%d" (addCounter ())

let k = Console.ReadKey()
```

Your version does this: it calls `addCounter` once and assigns the result-value `1` to `firstCounter` - so of course you get the same answer if you evaluate `firstCounter` (which is really just an integer) multiple times.

The part with the closure is that `counter` is captured by the function `fun () -> incr counter; !counter` and it's a rather common thing to use in F# (who needs classes to capture state if you can use a closure - indeed classes (and their methods) and closures have a lot in common!

### your additional question

if you want to create counters on the fly you can do it like this:

```
let createCounter() = 
    let counter = ref 0
    (fun () -> incr counter; !counter)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let c1 = createCounter()
    let c2 = createCounter()
    printfn "%d" (c1 ()) // -> "1"
    printfn "%d" (c2 ()) // -> "1"
    printfn "%d" (c1 ()) // -> "2"
    printfn "%d" (c1 ()) // -> "3"
    printfn "%d" (c2 ()) // -> "2"
```

#### what is going on here

now everytime you call `createCounter` a new `ref`-cell is created and a function to increase and return this is returned - so with every call you get a new counter with context and you just can use those as you used `addCounter` before

Comment: If I want to keep multiple state of addCounter how would do that? In Groovy, I can do the same by t1 = addCunter() and then every time I call t1, the counter increases in its context. If I would create t2 = addCounter and run t2, it will start from 0. SO based the answer, I will not able to do it in F#?

Comment: I added a bit to answer this - it's indeed rather easy to do (a simple `()` in the right place will do)

Comment: just curious what is '!' in '!counter' mean?

Comment: This operator get's the value from a ref-cell (`counter` is one)